# CSS make two divs equidistant inside of a wrapper div

Tags: css, html, space

Please view my code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/D6MUq/37/). What I am trying to do is quite simple, so it seems. I am trying to make the two boxes (one yellow, one green) in the purple box equidistant. So, I want the spacing from the purple box's left border to the green box's left border to be equal distance between the green box's right border and the yellow box's left border, which will also be equidistant to the space between the yellow box's right border to the purple box's right border.

I am all out of ideas, but I think I am close.

Thank you for any help with this!

Evan

Comment: If everything is fixed width, why can't you just set fixed `margin`s to do it? Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: /37 is the highest jsfiddle i've seen yet

Comment: I keep going back to it for different tests :)

Comment: @thirtydot I originally did just set the margins - I did the math to get 66.6px between each. For some reason though, this just aligned them on top of one another.

Comment: @qntmfred try 230... tries until I got it right for some animations I tried to make :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `float: left` on the left box and `float: right;` on the right box: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/D6MUq/38/

Comment: @feela, I'm sorry but you misread / misunderstood the question at hand. I want there to be spacing on the left and right of each box as well.

Comment: @feela hmm it seems you are correct. For some reason when i tried the margin idea it just stacked the boxes up on one another. Perhaps it was just the floats i was forgetting?

Comment: If you want to have equal width on all pink distances, you will need fixed widths for all elements and calculate the distances and widths for every element by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I am doing this now - I was just confused what I had messed on before. I will report back soon.

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty good:

```
#templatetypes {
    width: 150px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-left:13%;
    float:left;
    }

#supportlinks {
    width: 150px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-right:13%;
    float:right;
    }
```

Comment: This is the math I just came up with as well.